# Pagination not working on search results page - Wordpress Blocks Editor

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm facing an issue on a wordpress website. Custom block theme based on bootstrap.
I'm using the default search feature of wordpress (?s=my_query), in my files I don't have the file 'search.php'. This is where I gets the query value from:

```
<form class="d-flex" action="/" method="GET">
   <input name="s" type="text">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Then, in my editor, I have a template page of type 'search'.

[Search template page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeLLR.png)

The search feature is working, I mean, if I search 'sport' I go to the search-results page and I see x results with that query. I'm using the query loop block for display the results inside my search-results page.

BUT, if I wanna use the query loop pagination, there is a problem: I have the correct number of pages (generic word returns a lot of pages, instead a specific one only one page of results), but I can't navigate them. If I click on the page 2 of the pagination, the website goes to the 404 page. But I know that there is the second page of results, so this page exists, but seems that the url it's not working somehow.

[page 2 of search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVGMc.png)

How can I do? Suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

p.s. I tried to change the number of 'posts per page' of the query and it worked, but in this case the best result should be 10 posts per page and pagination. The solution tried shows me all the results and the page becomes too heavy. Then there is not a lot of documentation for my case.